# Как считать response из fetch для внешнего использования

Tags: javascript, fetch

Мне нужно использовать response значение во внешнем коде. Я пытался присваивать переменную как показано в коде и при попытке считать переменную вне блока .then получил undefined. Слышал что это можно и нужно делать используя IIFE. Буду благодарен вдвойне за такой пример.

```
let userName;
fetch('/api/verifytoken', {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        token: document.cookie
    })
    })
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => userName = response.message)
console.log(userName)
```

Comment: `const response = await fetch(....)` https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: Прежде чем читать переменную, нужно сперва **дождаться** момента, когда в эту переменную будет помещено значение.

Comment: @Jour Это работает. Но результат записывается обещанием (Promice). Как я могу сделать так чтобы в response устанавливалось значение? Спасибо!

Comment: Читайте в ответе дубликате. Можно даже этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476674/191482